# How to move xfce4 to USB Drive

Tags: xfce, chromebook

So I installed xfce4 on my chromebook (acer c720, model:Gnawty) and I am trying to move it from my ssd to my USB.

I got this error:

```
'chronos@localhost / $ sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce -p /media/removable/USB\ Drive
/media/removable/USB Drive/chroots/precise is not an ext filesystem.'
```

My USB is already a ext4 file system (I used gparted)

How do I fix this?